# How would I get started in auditing and finding vulnerabilities in encryption algorithms?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key

I know, it sounds dumb. Very dumb in fact. But regardless, I want to actually begin doing security research on cryptographic algorithms (SHA, RSA, ECDSA, etc.). I would prefer that this question be focused on auditing and finding vulnerabilities in the actual algorithms themselves. What resources should I begin looking at to get started in auditing the actual algorithms? I'm really willing to put in the massive work required but it's a bit difficult if I don't know where to start. I know it's dumb, but I still want to try my hand at it and eventually succeed. (auditing and breaking the actual algorithms)

Stuff on cryptanalysis is also welcome, but again, I'd like to keep this one focused on the actual algorithms themselves.

EDIT: For clarity, what I'm asking is this: What resources are available for a beginner like me to begin learning cryptanalysis and begin performing cryptanalysis on modern encryption algorithms? (And also asking where to start)

Comment: Finding weaknesses/vulnerabilities in cryptography algorithms (as opposed to implementations) is not normally referred to as auditing, but cryptanalysis.

Comment: So what exactly are you asking? It does not look like you have problems with English either. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't using the right terminology, but essentially my question was this: What resources are there for beginners to learn cryptanalysis and get started performing cryptanalysis on cryptographic algorithms?